# Why does CSS style 'background-color: #ffffff;' make the Composite transparent?

Tags: java, css, swt, eclipse-rcp

I am developing some custom controls for use in an RCP app. One control is a couple of `Labels` on a `Composite`. I gave the `Composite` a CSS Id and tried to apply this style:

```
#ImageSelectorButton, #ImageSelectorButton > *
{
    font-size: 28pt;
    color: rgb(51, 204, 153);
    background-color: #ffffff;
}
```

When the app starts, the control is displayed but the background is transparent. I tried using `background-color: rgb(255,255,255,255);` but the result is the same.

If the style is changed to `background-color: #fffffe;` the background is (almost) white and opaque.

Is this a bug or working as intended?

Comment: Are you sure you are targeting the correct element? Also do share the html.

Comment: @hunzaboy This is CSS for styling SWT code, there is no HTML.

Comment: Oh ok :) . well you `background-color: rgb(255,255,255,255);` is wrong , the 4th items is betwen 0 and 1.